# corresponding align

Tags: tables

How to align first and second part od table please?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                            c
                            S[table-format=1.6(2)]
                            S[table-format=5.3(2)]
                            S[table-format=1.4(2)]
                            S[table-format=3.1(2)]
                            cc 
                            }
\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
&&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\makecell[t]{Číslo\\ zdroje}
    &   {\makecell[t]{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
        &   {\makecell[t]{$i$\\ (\si{\degree})}}
            &   {\makecell[t]{$q = \frac{M_2}{M_1}$}}
                &   {\makecell[t]{$\omega$\\ (\si{\degree})}}
                    &   {\makecell[t]{$i$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
                        &   {\makecell[t]{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}    \\
    \midrule
5 & 43,9(3)         & 81,0(11)          &   0,3821              &               &               &       \\


\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{Pozn:}
Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer.}
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table} 

    \end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\newcommand\stack[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \small\centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} 
            c
            S[table-format=3.2(2)]
            S[table-format=3.2(2)]
            S[table-format=1.4]
            S[table-format=2.3(2)]
            S[table-format=2.3(2)]
            S[table-format=6.0] 
        }\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
        &&&&&&\\[-10pt]
        \shortstack{Číslo\\ zdroje}
        &   \stack{$q = \dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$}
        &   \stack{$M_1$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}
        &   \stack{$M_2$ \\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}
        &   \stack{$R_1$\\ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$)}
        &   \stack{$R_2$\\ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$)}
        &   \stack{$V_{\gamma}$\\ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})}    \\\midrule
        5 & 43,9(3)         & 81,0(11)          &   0,3821              &3,534(55)  &   
        5,615(84)   &   30000   \\
        6 & 43,0(24) &      76,4                &   0,3906          &           
        &               &               \\
        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \end{tabular}

\smallskip
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\textit{Pozn:}
Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer. $^*$značí fixované 
parametry.}

    \caption{Příklady zjištěných parametrů II}          
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to accommodate number of digits in `S` column with number of digits in table. it would be more easy to help you if you will populate your table with two more rows and also show us what is in the last three columns (now are empty).

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions, which is by itself fine. What is perhaps less optimal is that you seem not to want to make the questions clearer when others ask you to do so. (I am not one of those who asked you to make the question clearer, but if I was, I might be a little bit irritated that rather than responding to these requests you just add other questions. Wouldn't it help everyone more if you asked less but clearer questions?)

Comment: I am one of the people who have tried to help you by posting answers to your earlier, hard-to-understand postings. If anything, your latest postings have become even harder to understand. For instance, what does "How to align first and second part od table" even mean? I, for one, will no longer bother to figure out what's you're trying to achieve or how your code may be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\newcommand\stack[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \small\centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{} 
                c
                S[table-format=3.2(2)]
                S[table-format=3.2(2)]
                S[table-format=1.4]
                S[table-format=2.3(2)]
                S[table-format=2.3(2)]
                S[table-format=6.0] 
            }\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
            &&&&&&\\[-10pt]
            \shortstack{Číslo\\ zdroje}
            &   \stack{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}
            &   \stack{$i$\\ ($\si{\degree}$)}
            &   \stack{$q = \dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$}
            &   \stack{$\Omega_1$\\ ($\si{\degree}$)}
            &   \stack{$\Omega_2$\\ ($\si{\degree}$)}
            &   \stack{$T_1$\\ ($\mathrm{K}$)}    \\\midrule
            5 & 43,9(3)         & 81,0(11)          &   0,3821              &3,534(55)  &   
            5,615(84)   &   30000$^*$   \\
            6 & 43,0(24) &      76,4$^*$                &   0,3906          &           
            &               &               \\

            \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
        \end{tabular}

    \smallskip
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\textit{Pozn:}
    Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer. $^*$značí fixované 
    parametry.}

        \caption{Příklady zjištěných parametrů II}          
    \end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. And 5.3(2) mean 5 numbers before comma, 3 after comma? And what is in the brakets? I try to add a column (see edit) and I wan't sucessful.

Comment: see edited answer. I changed `\makecell` to `\shortstack` with `\multicolumn`. And yes `6.3(2)` is 6 digits before and 3 after the dot and additionally two digits in parentheses.

Comment: Thank you and is it please possible to center the preambule in the vertical direction?

Comment: And please I need a table twice, so I change a little bit a preambule and it doesn't work. Where I make a mistake? The code is in edit.

Comment: I edited your code. You had one `}` too many  at the end, eg: ` \stack{$R_2$\\ ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$)}`

Answer (score 0):

by exploiting loaded packages and on the basis of the my previous answer on yours (almost the same) questions:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,},
            table-align-text-post=false]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            c
                            S[table-format=2.1(1)]
                            S[table-format=2.1(2)]
                            S[table-format=1.4]
                            S[table-format=1.3(2)]
                            S[table-format=1.3(2)]
                            S[table-format=5.0,
                              table-space-text-post={*}]
                            }
    \toprule
\makecell{Číslo\\ zdroje}
    &   {\makecell{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
        &   {\makecell{$i$\\ (\si{\degree})}}
            &   {\makecell{$q = \frac{M_2}{M_1}$}}
                &   {\makecell{$\omega$\\ (\si{\degree})}}
                    &   {\makecell{$i$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}
                        &   {\makecell{$a$\\ ($\mathrm{M}_{\odot}$)}}    \\
    \midrule
            5 & 43,9(3)         & 81,0(11)          &   0,3821              &3,534(55)  &
            5,615(84)   &   30000$^*$   \\
            6 & 43,0(24) &      76,4$^*$                &   0,3906          &
            &               &               \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{Pozn:}
Čísla v závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer.}
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]